# How to parse android log in realtime while running unittest with Appium?

Tags: android, python, appium, ui-automation

I am running UI automation test with Appium. But it is does not recognize my elements on the screen. I added Debug messages to the source code and built new apk with those messages.

What i need to do next is start UI test and at same time grab logfile --> read from log for Debug message i added and if my text string is displayed --> assert and mark as pass.

Example: 
1. Start Test "launch app"
2. Verify that text "hello world" is displayed on first load page
But appium does not see this text due to my app complexity, so, to assert the correct text string i need to look from realtime logs and than put results in my unittest Pass or Fail 
3. And if i need to make any logic in the app(go to settings, go to profile page etc) i have to wait for specific Text string, even if i have time.sleep, it is not guarantee that text will be displayed.

Is there an appropriate way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `adb logcat` if you have the android sdk tools intalled. Or install android studio and read the logcat in there.

Comment: yes, correct, i can read from logcat. But my goal is read for text string, while running python unittest test. I will update my post, maybe i was not really clear. Thanks!